# CSS to make my sidebar menu into buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm a Java programmer that's been tasked to make a website; could someone who's a web designer, and good with CSS, please help me?

I have a main page that has a side bar menu that is just a regular list that I would like to turn into buttons (because no one likes boring lists).

```
<div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

And CSS:

```
.menu{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100% !important;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  background-color: #627F5F;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Everywhere I go to look at some tutorials I just get examples of how I could buy a plugin or just someone's that I can rip. So: any cool CSS tricks that I can play with would be appreciated. Or any cool ones that are out there that I could use and customize would be cool too.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: All you need to do is style your `<li>`'s in such a way that they look like buttons. Such as `border-radius` and background gradient.

Comment: I really dont know how to make buttons is there like....a button tag that i can use or do i have to style the <li> to have some style on it....and if thats the only way then how do i style the <li> O.o

Comment: Define 'cool,' you seem to be convinced that's the way to go, but give no idea as to what, precisely, that means to you. What do you want them to look like, exactly?

Comment: Making things "cool" is not a programming style. Any way you could be more specific, without using colourful and meaningless metaphors? Have a read through [ask] if you need some help.

Comment: But thanks EternalHour for giving actual suggestions....which got some ideas rolling my noob web dev brain :)

Comment: Try this: http://www.cssmenubuilder.com/home

Comment: I would say cool is the opposite to plain text. Please mark my answer as correct if you liked it, thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your *boring lists* can be turned into eye-candy and user-friendly menus with a little knowledge of CSS.

To begin, check the list samples from the site below, they are very easy to understand even if your CSS knowledge equals *null*. The CSS and HTML code is ready to copy+paste, and then charge money for that.

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/

I'll also provide you **free of charge** these cool color palettes from Google to further customize your list colors:

http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-ui-color-palette

Answer (score 1):

Use something like below..

```
li {
    list-style:none;
    background-color:black;
    margin:5px 0px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:5px 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3zvq18t4/)

Make suitable change as you need..

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to try this css for make button of you UL Li

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fzvs5x99/)

this css

```
ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
   margin:2px 0;

}
ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:red;

}
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100% !important;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    background-color: #627F5F;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots ways to do a menu, but given your HTML, I would stick to the `<ul>`/`<li>` markup. There's several styles you can apply to give your buttons a "cool" look such as a background gradient and box shadows.

This should get you headed in the right direction.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdgr24yc/)

**HTML:** (uses what you already have)

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu ul {
    width: 200px;
    list-style-type: none; //removes bullets//
}
.menu li {
    border-radius: 3px; //provides rounded corners//
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(12, 133, 12, 1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(12, 133, 12, 1) 0%, rgba(114, 191, 95, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(12, 133, 12, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(114, 191, 95, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(12, 133, 12, 1) 0%, rgba(114, 191, 95, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(12, 133, 12, 1) 0%, rgba(114, 191, 95, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(12, 133, 12, 1) 0%, rgba(114, 191, 95, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(12, 133, 12, 1) 0%, rgba(114, 191, 95, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0c850c', endColorstr='#72bf5f', GradientType=0);
}
.menu li a {
    display: block; //makes entire <li> clickable//
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
}
```

I used http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator for the gradients.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this jsfiddle :
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4js3runn/3/

```
#cssmenu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
    font-family: "Oxygen Mono",Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
#cssmenu {
    border: 0 none;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}#cssmenu ul, #cssmenu ul li, #cssmenu ul ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 597;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
    width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 1em;
    min-height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
    float: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    border-right: 4px solid #1b9bff;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu a {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a, a:visited, a:link {
    color: #30708c;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1b9bff;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after {
    content: "+";
    margin-top: -6px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 50%;
}#cssmenu ul ul {left: 99%;  visibility: hidden;position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #0082e7;border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;   width: 200px;margin-top: 1px;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 1em;
    min-height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0082e7; font-weight: normal; float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after {
    content: "+";
    margin-top: -6px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 50%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    right: 0;
    top: -2px;
}
#cssmenu ul li {  width: 100%;}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1b9bff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul{visibility: visible;}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul{visibility: visible;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your markup then you can use these simple css lines, which doesnot require any js or any plugin.

```css
.menu {
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    background: #eee;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.menu:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}
.menu:hover ul,
.menu:focus ul,
.menu:active ul {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

You can add your effects.
Have a great code day.